# Ionic native photo-viewer can't load image in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, photoviewer

I am using ionic-photo-viewer (1.1.10 ),when i click on the image,it shows the blank black modal with loader ,cancel and share button but after sometime the loader and the modal was dismissed and it gives me the error message "Error loading image". Please help me.